# Speeding up slow function with lots of SQL Calls

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to generate a report which returns a set of numbers for a given time scale.

For instance I need to return the minutes watched for a given month. Here is what I run at the moment

```
presentation = Presentation.find(1)
presentation.video.stats.minutes_by_date(Date.new(2012,6,1),Date.new(2012,6,30))


def self.by_date(start_date,end_date)
    vals = Array.new
    (start_date..end_date).map { |date|
      yesterdays_stat = daily_watched(date.yesterday)
      todays_stat = daily_watched(date)

      if todays_stat > 0
        if yesterdays_stat > 0
          difference = todays_stat - yesterdays_stat
        else
          difference = todays_stat
        end
        watched_in_meg = (difference / 1024).round(2)
        vals.push (watched_in_meg / first.video.meg_per_minute).round(2)
      else
        vals.push 0
      end
    }
    vals
  end

  def self.daily_watched(date)
    # get the total bytes for the from both flash and mp4
    total_bytes = 0
    bytes = where(["DATE(generated_date) = ?", date]).group("kbytes")
    .order('generated_date')
    bytes.each do |byte|
      total_bytes += byte.kbytes
    end
    total_bytes
    # Get the bytes of both flash and mp4
  end
```

The output needs to looks like this:

`[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 54.09, 54.09, 54.09, 54.09, 54.09, 54.09, 54.09, 54.09, 54.09, 54.09, 0]`

The problem is this has to run 30 times per presentation and I have anywhere from 10 to 500 presentations.

Is there a way of making this more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

You can start by getting the stats for all of the dates with a single query and then calculate the differences with one pass over the array.

the query can look roughly like that:

```
result = Thing.select("DATE(generated_date) as date, SUM(kbytes) as sum_kbytes").group("DATE(generated_date)").where...
result.each{|i| puts "#{i.date} #{i.sum_kbytes}"}
```

Comment: This works well but the issue I am having is I need it to pad the other days where no data was returned with a 0 how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Precalculate the difference var for each presentation for each day. Then read from precalculated table in this function.